# ruby-cms-scanner : Depends: ruby-progressbar (>= 1.9.0) but it is not installed

Tags: ruby, parrot-os

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ruby-progressbar_1.10.1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/ruby-progressbar/base.rb', which is also in package ruby-ruby-progressbar 1.6.0-0kali1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ruby-progressbar_1.10.1-1_all.deb
Scanning application launchers
Updating active launchers
Done
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Where is the above error coming from? A log file or the command line? What command did you run?

Comment: sudo apt --fix-broken install

Comment: I would try to deinstall the `ruby-progressbar` gem and reinstall it before running the command you actually want to run.

Comment: could you please tell me steps

Answer (score 2):

Try the below:

```
dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/ruby-progressbar_1.10.1-1_all.deb
apt --fix-broken -f install
```

Comment: I'm very thankful to you

Comment: Worked perfectly, so glad this is fixed thank you.